# Angular Material md-slider: Vertical Slider will not work in md-sidenav

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

Actual behavior:

What is the issue? * 
The md-slider cannot be placed vertically in the md-sidenav https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/sidenav material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/slider

What is the expected behavior? 
When I add md-vertical attribute to the md-slider it will be vertical in any part of the project, however when placed in the md-sidenav it stays horizontal

Plnkr which shows issue https://embed.plnkr.co/7lBplI/
Details: Note how when sidebar is open the md-slider is horizontal and not vertical despite have the vertical attribute Angular Versions: *
Angular Version: 1.5.3
Angular Material Version: 1.0.9
Additional Information:

Browser Type: * chrome: latest version
Browser Version: * Chrome: latest
OS: * Mac: OSX 10.10.5

Comment: Please add your code directly to your question, not links to your code.

Comment: Exceeds character limit, sorry

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are using an old version of Angular Material. According to the header of your **angular-material.js** file it shows version **v0.5.1**. I think you've combined all the minified JS files into **docs.js** and it's not possible to see the version within that or **angular-material.min.js**.

I have stripped down your example - [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kJZasR?p=preview) - to match a working [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/zBNqgV?editors=1010) example. As you can see, the CodePen works as expected.

Update Angular Material to the latest version (**v1.1.0**) and it should work fine.

CodePen Markup

```
<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-md')" md-disable-backdrop="" md-whiteframe="4">
  <div layout-padding="" ng-controller="LeftCtrl">
    <md-slider-container flex>
      <md-slider ng-model="vol" min="0" max="100" aria-label="volume" id="volume-slider" class="md-accent" md-vertical md-range>
      </md-slider>
  <h5>Volume</h5>
  </md-slider-container>
    <p hide="" show-gt-md="">
      This sidenav is locked open on your device. To go back to the default behavior,
      narrow your display.
    </p>
  </div>
</md-sidenav>

<md-content flex="" layout-padding="">
  <div layout="column" layout-fill="" layout-align="top center">
    <div>
      <md-button ng-click="toggleLeft()" class="md-primary" hide-gt-md="">
        Toggle left
      </md-button>
    </div>
  </div>
</md-content>
```

Comment: Hi I am using the latest angular/ angular material on my machine, all dependencies are ok- and all material elements are working fine, with the exclusion of this case. Apologies it seems your codepen is not working on my machine so I cannot see the working example

Comment: @eliber I did a search for the string "md-vertical" in your **docs.js** and **angular-material.min.js** and it is not found. It is found in my **angular-material.min.js**.

Comment: thanks, I've triple checked, it seems everything on my machine is working however after starting the project from scratch I can not get the slider to appear vertically in sidenav, The slider does appear vertically when I use it standalone, but does not work in the sidebar.